# Travis build fails due to badly outdated NPM

Tags: travis-ci

I'm looking to use Travis CI.  I am erroring out due to failures during npm install.  I noticed it can't find file versions marked with `^`.  This character was added [recently](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/).  Looking at the build output I noticed:

$ npm --version
1.2.30

My development machine runs npm 2.5.1.  I did not see any way to upgrade npm in the Travis CI Settings.  I manually changed my package.json to use `~` and that seems to have helped as I got more output:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "~2.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.7",
    "karma-cli": "0.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.16"
  }
```

However, I still get errors and these errors also display file version issues and use `^`.

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - "npm install -g npm@'>=2.5.0'"
```

That resolved my build failure.